# how to use inner class out side of current package

Tags: java, inner-classes

I have an inner class which is present inside a method and this class has a method.

I want to use the method which is present in my inner class method outside of my current package.
Can you suggest me how to use it?

```
package com.a3.local;
public class OuterClass
{
    public void outerMethod()
    {
        class InnerClazz
        {
            public void wakeUp()
            {
                System.out.println("Good Morning");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: An example would go a long way here...

Comment: Is it really an inner class? I think you probably meant an anonymous (inner) classes I guess. Perhaps post some code?

Comment: Perhaps you need to rethink how your code is structured - some refactoring to extract the method you want to reuse and give it different (`public`) visibility might be in order?

Comment: package com.a3.local;

public class OuterClass {
 
 public void outerMethod()
 {
  class InnerClazz
  {
   public void wakeUp()
   {
    System.out.println("Good Morning");
   }
  }
 }

}

Comment: hey i have posted my code and i wna use wakeUp() method out side this package.

Comment: @subodh ray, you can either make InnerClazz implement an interface, as described in my answer below, or move it outside the method but still inside OuterClass (making InnerClazz a non-static member class).

Answer (score 2):

As others explained you can access to your method local defined inner-class (using an interface => see other answers).

Anyway I don't think this is the purpose of defining a method-local class.

Comment: External callers can call methods on the inner class defined in a method. This is the whole point to anonymous inner classes.

Comment: @Andy Thomas-Cramer: I don't get it. Could you explain to me why a "method local" inner-class purpose is to be called by others?

Comment: @reef, see the first example at http://java.sun.com/new2java/divelog/part5/page5.jsp. The *actionPerformed* method in the anonymous inner class is called by code in a different package.

Comment: @Andy Thomas-Cramer: Ok but it's not a method local inner-class. Am I wrong?

Comment: @Andy Thomas-Cramer: I agree that if your method local inner class implements a public interface you can instanciate it and return this instance to the caller so that it uses a very specific interface implementation. But I don't think this is the purpose of defining a method local inner-class.

Comment: @reef, I claimed it was the point to anonymous inner classes. Local inner classes could be used for other purposes. In both cases, the questioner's goal to "use the method" in the inner class is feasible. Your answer could be misread to suggest that it is not.

Comment: @Andy Thomas-Cramer: 'Your answer could be misread to suggest that it is not.' => you're right indeed. Answer modified.

Answer (score 2):

We can access the inner class method outside the package. 
We need to create an instance of the Outerclass and then create an instance of the inner class using the outer class. After that we can call it.

**code from tutorial : http://www.oursland.net/tutorials/java/innerclasses/**

```
    public class InnerClassTest {
        public void foo() {
            System.out.println("Outer class");
        }

        public class ReallyInner {
            public void foo() {
                System.out.println("Inner class");
            }

            public void test() {
                this.foo();
                InnerClassTest.this.foo();
            }
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            InnerClassTest o = new InnerClassTest();
            InnerClassTest.ReallyInner i = o.new ReallyInner();
            i.test();
```

Comment: Thanks a ton man, i have searched everywhere but found the solution here. Very useful answer.

Answer (score 1):

If the inner class is defined in a method, calling its methods (without reflection) requires that:

- The class implement an interface accessible to the caller.
- An instance of the class is accessible to the caller.

There's an example at http://java.sun.com/new2java/divelog/part5/page5.jsp .

Comment: The first condition could be circumvented by using Reflection, though.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understood the code looks like:

```
class Outer
{
  public void someMethod()
  {
    class Inner{
      public void methodThatShouldBeVisibleOutside() {}
    }
  }
}
```

The only way is to have the `Inner` class implements a publicly visible interface 'InnerInterface' and return an instance of the `Inner` class and invoke the `methodThatShouldBeVisibleOutside`:

```
public InnerInterface someMethod()
{
  class Inner implements InnerInterface()
  {
    @Override
    public void methodThatShouldBeVisibleOutside() {}
  }
  return new Inner();
}
```

Then

```
new Outer().someMethod().methodThatShouldBeVisibleOutside();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your class has to be `public` and have a name and be defined in the class body, not inside a method for you to be able to use it in other packages directly, instead of just using it by its base type or one of its interface types.

If you have a class `mypackage.Outer` that defines an inner `class Inner`, you can refer to the class using the name `mypackage.Outer.Inner` and import that as normal to shorten the name.

If it's static, you can create it using the `new mypackage.Outer.Inner(...)`.

If it's not static, you have to use a different syntax to create them : `myOuterInstance.new mypackage.Outer.Inner(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your inner class must have a public visibility and be static.

Then, there's two possibilities :

1. You want to call a static method of your inner class
2. You want to call a method on an instance of your inner class

In the first case, if the visibility are setted right, you can simply do :

```
OuterClass.InnerClass.myStaticMethod()
```

In the seconde class, you must provide a way to retrieve an instance of the inner class and simply invoke the method on the instance as you'll do with any other method.

It is also possible to call a method on a non static inner class, but this is way more complicated. A code snippet will really helps here ;)

Hope this helps.

Comment: If it's a mthod local inner class you cannot make it public as for classic local variables.

Comment: if the class is created inside a method, it's an anonymous class, not an inner class. But rereading the question, it seems the authors used the wrong word...

Comment: The inner class need not have public visibility. It is sufficient to provide an instance that implements a public interface.

Comment: anonymous classes *are* inner classes.